# Column names with pandas shift

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to create lags for pandas columns with `column_names`

Sample DF Code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(4,2)))
df.shift(1)
```

OP:

```
     0   1
0   NaN NaN
1   9.0 2.0
2   4.0 5.0
3   6.0 0.0
```

but when I try to create this with column names, i get `nan`

```
df1=pd.DataFrame(df.shift(1),columns=["lag"+str(each) for each in df.columns])
df1
```

OP:

```
    lag0  lag1
0   NaN   NaN
1   NaN   NaN
2   NaN   NaN
3   NaN   NaN
```

Any suggestion to rectify this?

Comment: Just use `add_prefix`. For that to work you'd need `df.shift(1).values`. Otherwise you're reindexing with unseen indices, which produces all NaNs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is there are different columns names, so after created new DataFrame columns names not matched and are created misisng values, it is called index alignmenet.

For prevent it is possible convert values to numpy array:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame(df.shift(1).to_numpy(),columns=["lag"+str(each) for each in df.columns])
print (df1)
   lag0  lag1
0   NaN   NaN
1   2.0   2.0
2   8.0   3.0
3   6.0   8.0
```

But simplier is use [`DataFrame.add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html):

```
df1 = df.shift().add_prefix('lag')
print (df1)
   lag0  lag1
0   NaN   NaN
1   1.0   1.0
2   8.0   3.0
3   0.0   4.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another approach:

```
df = df.shift(1)

l = list(df.columns.astype('str'))
s = 'lag'
cols = [s + i for i in l]
df.columns = cols
```

---

```
df
    lag0    lag1
0   NaN     NaN
1   7.0     4.0
2   4.0     8.0
3   0.0     9.0
```